# Удалить строки DelphiXE

Tags: delphi

**В текстовом файле есть строки:**

```
Документ№1:22.06.2018 
Документ№2:22.06.2018
Документ№3:22.06.2018
Документ№1:23.05.2018
Документ№1:25.05.2018
```

**Задача:** Удалить все дубликаты строк (оставив одну уникальную).

**Особое условие:** **Одинаковой**, считается строка, в которой, **до символа** **":"** - повторяются слова (в нашем случае - **Документ№1**).

**Результат на выходе:**

```
Документ№1:22.06.2018 
Документ№2:22.06.2018
Документ№3:22.06.2018
```

Стандартное, удаление дублирующих строк, сделать не проблема, для меня. А вот в данном случае, с задачей, не могу справиться.

Comment: И что вызывает трудности?

Comment: в стринглист какой нить valueseparator установить в `:` и загрузить содержимое, наверняка небось останутся уникальные записи только. правда скорее всего последение.

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, трудности в том что: подсчет дублирующих строк идет - с начала строки и до символа ":" В этом и вся загвоздка, у меня.

Comment: Вам помогут функции `Pos` и `Copy` или метод `String.Split`

Comment: @teran Не останутся. Загрузятся все записи. А вот `Values[]` будет возвращать первую запись для указанного имени

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, Уже пробовала, но без-успешно :(. Понимаю что решение простое, но пока что тупик - с решением, у меня.

Comment: Ну покажите как пробовали

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, Я пробовала вот так s := Copy(s,1,Pos(':',s)).

Comment: Замечательно пробовали. И что не устроило в результате?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, Ну а теперь не могу сделать код, что бы с этим параметром - быстро удалялись дубликаты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var
  Strings: TDictionary<string, string>;
  Str: string;
  Key: string;
begin
  Strings := TDictionary<string, string>.Create;
  try
    while ... do begin
      Str := ReadString;
      Key := Copy(Str, 1, Pos(':', Str) - 1);
      if not Strings.ContainsKey(Key) then
        Strings.Add(Key, Str);
    end;
    for Str in Strings.Values do
      WriteString(Str);
  finally
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Отличнейшее решение. Я в приятном шоке, даже и не думала что на столько все просто. Низкий поклон Вам - Anton Shchyrov!